# The class in ArcGIS SDK for Android like Googlemap for Android class overlay?

Tags: android, esri

I want to draw a circle on mapview using ArcGIS SDK for Android. Can't find any clue to do it. I did that in googlemap api for Android by overriding draw method in Overlay. Anyone can help with the class(in ArcGIS SDK for Android) and an example?